# Нужна помощь с алгоритмом на Java

Tags: java

Мне приходят данные в txt в виде:

`[json-massive1] text1 [json-massive2] text2 [json-massive3]` и т.д. по 100-200 в файле. Мне надо привести инфу к виду:

`[json-massive1] mytext1 [json-massive2] mytext2 [json-massive3]` т.е. менять text на mytext между всеми символами "]" "[".
Я могу заменить значения между первым и вторым массивом:

```
s1 = s.substring(s.indexOf("]") + 1);
s1 = s1.substring(0, s1.indexOf("["));
s2 = s.replace(s1, ",\"mytext\"" + 1 + ":" + "\n");
```

s - весь текст в файле.

Но не понимаю как правильно сделать цикл для большего количества, подскажите пожалуйста, как это лучше сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот регулярка:

```
\](.*?)\[
```

С её помощью Вы можете найти все текстовые значения между [json-massive].

```
// Инициализация
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(source);
// Обход совпадений с регуляркой
while (matcher.find())
{
    // Получаем найденный текст
    String text = matcher.group();
    // Далее формируем строку
    . . .
}
```

Как-то так.

Answer (score 2):

Ещё один простой способ изменить *text1...text(n)* на *mytext1...mytext(n)* используя тот же **Pattern**

```
int index = 1;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s"); //указываем пробел в качестве разделителя
String[] temp = pattern.split(text); //где text - текст файла преобразованный в String
for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
 if(temp[i].equals("text" + index)) {
  temp[i] = "mytext" + index;
  index++;
 }
}
```

Далее , если необходимо, записываем в файл с помощью классов **FileWriter** и **BufferedWriter**.
Выглядит примитивно но дает нужный результат